# Virtual Machine Platform turned on but Windows Subsystem for Android not working

Tags: windows, virtualization, hyper-v, windows-11, hypervisor

I want to use Windows Subsystem for Android on Windows 11. I encountered a problem while following the article in the [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/android/wsa/) step by step. When I try to open an app (in Amazon Store or files app in wsa menu) it gives me this error:

> Ensure that Virtual Machine Platform is enabled in optional Windows features. Ensure that your device has virtualization enabled in the bios...

I already have Virtual Machine Platform, Hyper-V and Hypervisor turned on in Windows features. And Intel virtualization technology turned on in bios.

[image: Windows features].

I found this commands in Web for turn on Hyper-V and Hypervisor on command line:

```
DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /All /FeatureName:Microsoft-Hyper-V
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto
```

However I'am still get same error.

I apologize if I missed something. Thanks...

Comment: Provide a screenshot that indicates the required optional features are installed. You have enabled Hyper-V with the command you used but that isn’t the correct optional feature

Comment: @Ramhound I already wrote "I already have Virtual Machine Platform, Hyper-V and Hypervisor turned on in Windows features.". But still I added the image you requested.

Comment: I would explicitly disable Hyper-V

Comment: @Ramhound Oh sorry... Now I disabled Hyper-V and still the same problem.

Comment: Do you have Core Isolation enabled? What other Hypervisors do you have installed? Within task manager does it indicate that virtualization is enabled? You are running the current developer channel insider preview build, correct?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes Core Isolation is enabled. VirtualBox 6.1 and VMWare Workstation Pro 16.2 installed. In task manager virtualization seems enabled. And yes I am running, 22000.xxx version of Windows.

Comment: Disable Core Isolation. In my experience Core Isolation interferes with using a Hypervisor like Hyper-V or using VMP compatible features like WSA and WSL2. VMWare and VirtualBox will also have to be uninstalled to verify they are not the source of the conflict

Comment: @Ramhound I have disabled Virtual Based Security and Memory Integrity. I have uninstalled VBox and VMWare. Still not working. When I turned off Virtual Based Security, 4 rows were added to [System info](https://imgur.com/5HVfzsQ), but Hyper-V is still turned off. Is that a problem?

Comment: It’s still turned off because the first thing you did was disable it.  I am now wondering if you were to enable it, create a VM, if you would now be able to start it.  I realize that wasn’t or isn’t an issue you reported, but it’s a diagnostic step, only other help diagnostic step you could do involves testing if WSL2 works.  Do you happen to have anything connected to Android other than WSA installed? Do you happen to have Docker installed?

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry for the late reply, I forgot here. Yes Docker is installed. I closed WSL2 a few days ago and when I turned it back on, Docker Engine stopped working. As you said, it may be related to Docker, I'll try to delete it.

Comment: @TuranBerlin Did you figure this out?